# How to make a BW plot to show the data

Tags: r

I have extracted seeds from the seed bank ,  under the tree crown and 3 m away the crown. I have these data for three study sites in two countries, south Australia and Sri Lanka (a part of the data is attached). The script I used to develop a BW plot using lattice is given below. In fact I have prepared two plots here separately for the two countries. I want to develop this graph. I want to show data of one country (South Australia) on one side of the plot(beneath crown and 3m away in 2 colors) and the other side the other country (Sri Lanka) same two colors to show beneath crown and 3 m away.

[image: Part of the dataset]

```
setwd("E:/Research/Fieldwork SL-data/Seed bank/analysis")

seed.bank <- read.csv(file="seedbank_rev.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
attach(seed.bank)
names(seed.bank)
## [1] "seed.no."   "location"   "study.site" "country"   

seed.bank1<-seed.bank[!(country=="Sri Lanka"),]
seed.bank2<-seed.bank[!(country=="South Australia"),]

library("lattice")

bwplot(log(seed.no.) ~ study.site | location, data=seed.bank1, xlab="Study Sites in South Australia", ylab="log(seed number)")
bwplot(log(seed.no.) ~ study.site | location, data=seed.bank2, xlab="Study Sites in Sri Lanka", ylab="log(seed number)")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Please click on the "r' below your question, then click on the "info" tag and read up on how to post a decent question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple R base solution to what *seems* to be your problem is a barplot (since you have categorical variables):

```
# define dataframe:
df <- data.frame(
  location = c(rep("beneath",1), rep("at_distance",4),rep("beneath",4), rep("at_distance",3)),
  country = c(rep("SA",6),rep("SL",6))
)

# check structure:
str(df)
```

This step reveals that the data are formatted as factors. These need to be converted to characters to obtain frequency counts:

```
# convert factors to characters:
df <- lapply(df, as.character)

# make frequency table:
freq_seeds <- table(df$country, df$location)
```

Now you are ready to plot the data; the key argument to place the corresponding bars side by side is `beside=TRUE`:

```
# define plotting region:
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(4,4,4,4))
# barplot:
barplot(freq_seeds, beside=T, main="Seeds", col=c("blue", "green"))
# draw legend:
legend("topright", c("South Australia", "Sri Lanka"), fill=c("blue", "green"), col=c("blue", "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick response. However I want to show data across study sites too. If I can show SA data left side of the plot across study sites using two bars together for beneath crown and 3m away AND SL data on the right side of the plot across sites ....

Comment: Not sure I can help you with this. What you CAN do is plot `$country`in the bars, thus: 1. change the order of the variables in the table, thus: `freq_seeds1 <- table(df$location, df$country)`, 2. plot this new frequency list: `barplot(freq_seeds1, beside=T, main="Seeds", 
        ylab="Frequency", xlab="Country",
        col=c("blue", "green"))`and finally change the legend accordingly: `legend("topright", c("at distance", "beneath"), fill=c("blue", "green"), col=c("blue", "green"), bty="n")`. This will get you two bars for `$location` for each country (but nothing for study site!)